# Authenticating user for Sharepoint Online in client/server environment

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sharepoint, client-server, sharepoint-online

Currently, I am developing a website (for internal usage) which requires retrieving of certain data from my corporate's SharePoint page.
Below will be the code used:

```
    Using ctx As ClientContext = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext("https://abc.sharepoint.com")

        If ctx IsNot Nothing Then

            web = ctx.Web
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web)
            ctx.ExecuteQuery()

        End If
    End Using
```

For now, I am able to authenticate users using *ClaimsClientContext* 
testing in my *localhost*. However after I published the website and deploy onto my server, it does not work. Can anyone point me towards the right direction on how to authenticate users in the client/server environment?

Comment: `ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext` should display you a form to supply credentials is this happening?

Comment: Hi @tinamou, it displays as a pop up when i test it locally. but when i deploy it to my server, when users access the webpage it just keeps on loading and no form being shown.